# Maximum N-noded connected subgraph in a node-weighted graph

Tags: java, graph, graph-algorithm, genetic-algorithm, subgraph

Take this node weighted graph for example :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEYJD.png]

- The maximum subgraph containing exactly 1 node (and the 'entry point') would be 14.
- The maximum subgraph containing exactly 2 nodes (and the 'entry point') would be 14 / 9.
- The maximum subgraph containing exactly 3 nodes (and the 'entry point') would be 3 / 19 / 15.
- The maximum subgraph containing exactly 4 nodes (and the 'entry point') would be 14 / 1 / 7 / 240.

I can't manage to think of a better method than a bruteforce to get the maximum subgraph.
And if there is no known efficient algorithm, would a genetic algorithm be find in that case (the crossovers seem tricky) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can modify [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to solve this problem.

With Dijkstra's algorithm, you are solving the shortest path. Just change that to find the maximum path. To restrict it to only 1, 2, 3 nodes in a graph, keep track of the number of nodes it takes to get to each node when you "visit it". Stop when there are no other nodes with a count less than the number of nodes you are looking for.

Comment: Since it's not a path but a subgraph, I don't see how could a modified Dijkrasta be possible. For a 4 nodes subgraph for example the solution could be the points 14 / 1 / 15 / 7. Am I missing something ?